# What are the main differences between Catholicism and Protestantism?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, comparative-christianity

I’m interested mainly in values and philosophical differences in terms of the general worldviews and broader views on life, but welcome any answer  that may be offered.

Comment: This question is way too broad and has already been dealt with in several questions. Please have a read of some of the linked questions, as well as resources like Wikipedia, and then ask some more focused follow on questions.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between their philosophical and theological methods? I would say that you could even ask how Eastern and Western Catholic traditions differ when it comes to that.  You are asking a very broad question.